# Which Integration strategies are there?

Tags: architecture, integration

We are having a discussion about Integration strategies.

The main argument is about what is a strategy and what is a technique. For example Hub-and-Spoke is a strategy, but REST is a technique. Or maybe not?

What would be your list of integration strategies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue the two most important strategies are:

- Service calling (Real-time
  integration), and
- Batch Calling

My take is that the following are integration techniques:

- Hub-and-spoke,
- Publish and subscribe,
- Point-to-point, and
- Large file transfers

REST and SOAP are Web Service Calls / patterns.